# Why isn't Label shown when setting setLabelForComponent for a TextField?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textfield, lwuit-label, lwuit-container

There are `Label`, `TextField` and a `Container` in a Form. I set :

```
...
private Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
...
impay30 = new Label("Impayé 30j");
impay30.setUIID("FicheLibelle");
impay30.setPreferredW(LabellargeW);
impay30txt = new TextField();
impay30txt.setMaxSize(50);
impay30txt.addDataChangeListener(this);
VirtualKeyboard.bindVirtualKeyboard(impay30txt, vkNombre);
impay30txt.setLabelForComponent(impay30);
c.addComponent(impay30txt);
```

But in runtime the TextField are only displayed but the Label are not displayed ! So how to make the `Label` appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `impay30` into `Container(c)`. Then only its showing on the screen. `impay30` label is associate with `impay30txt` component when use `setLabelForComponent` and it will be used for start the ticker of the `Label` when the `Component` receives the focus.